# Overstay in Prague by one day

Tags: visas, air-travel, schengen, overstaying, czech-republic

This summer, my friend from Thailand will come to see me in Prague, Czech Repulic. He applied for a Schengen tourist visa type C and received it, valid for 30 days with **15** days of the stay.

Due to the miscalculations, he booked the following flights:
Arrival in Prague 28th July, 13:30 (1:30 pm)
Departure from Prague 12th August, 12:30 (12:30 pm, half past noon).

Overall it makes **16** days. He tried to change the flight back on 11th August, but is having problems.

The travel agency fees are too high to change the flight as well as the cost of the confirmation of the change for the international calls. Moreover, it isn't replying to his messages, so it is unlikely that he'll change the flight.

What are consequences of overstaying in Prague by 12 hours (technically one day) and what is the likely scenario? What can we do except canceling the flight? Is there a way to extend the duration of stay in Prague?

Comment: He could perhaps arrive at the airport the previous day and pass border control before midnight. It will at least show that he's trying to obey the rules.

Comment: @ugoren: Yes, I have think about that. However, how he can pass the border control withouth the boarding ticket that is issued at check-in that opens few hours before the departure?

Comment: @NikolasCharalambidis Check-in often opens 24 hours before departure, sometimes more.

Comment: Beware - the Czechs won't allow you to exit on an overstayed visa until you get an "exit visa". I definitely don't recommend exiting the Schengen border through Prague for that reason.

Comment: @JonathanReez Good to know but what's an “exit visa”? A stamp to the effect that you paid some sort of fee or fine?

Comment: @Relaxed AFAIK you go to the police office before immigration where they issue you a permit to leave the country. It's not a big deal, but it makes it much more likely you will be punished in according to the Schengen law.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A ban is probably legally possible but very unlikely. I assume a fine is also possible but not certain. With a bit of luck, they might also get away with a slap on the wrist. It could however become more difficult to secure another visa in the future.

But the consequences of the overstay is not the only thing you have to worry about: Border guards are perfectly entitled to examine your plans upon entering. If they notice the discrepancy, they can also revoke the visa and send your friends back to Thailand on the grounds that they don't have proper documentation for their intended stay. That would be much worse on every level.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Can we inform anyone at immigration or airport about this situation in advance?

Comment: @NikolasCharalambidis I don't think so and I don't see any basis for them to help you or change your visa. In principle, you should get the consulate in your friends' country of residence to amend their visa (although if it is your mistake, they might not care).

Comment: A much bigger likelihood is Thailand stopping you. The Czech border guards can say "15 days, 16 days, who cares". The airline in Thailand has to say "If the Czech border guards send him back, that will be very, very expensive for us. " I suspect this is not a risk that they are going to take.

Comment: @gnasher729 That's true as well.